# How to find a Shape in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

How should /can I find a specific shape on a worksheet in MS Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here as I can't find the original post, and there are numerous similar posts. In short, the best way to find a shape in a sheet is to loop through all the shapes in the sheet to find the one you are looking for. Such as:

```
...
For Each shp In .Shapes
    arrShapes(shp.ID, 0) = .Cells(shp.TopLeftCell.row, colItemNum).Value
    arrShapes(shp.ID, 1) = shp.TopLeftCell.Address
    arrShapes(shp.ID, 2) = shp.TopLeftCell.row
    arrShapes(shp.ID, 3) = shp.TopLeftCell.Column
Next shp
```

This code puts all the shapes into an array to search later.

WARNING! There are a few quirks I found in using this code!

MS Excel uses Shapes for Comments! If you have a comment in a cell, MS Excel will include this in the shapes for the sheet! These are AutoShapeType=msoShapeRectangle, so hard to distinguish from other text boxes. You can idnetify them where Type = msoComment. You can try to filter out *specific* comments by their default name, which is usually something like "Commentn" where n is simply a serial number. Not sure how they are numbered. The cell position references (UpperLeft,BottomRight, so on) refer to the placement of the text box for the comment WHEN DISPLAYED - NOT for the parent cell - although they are close.

The ID for shapes is not the same as the INDEX. For example, the first shape in a sheet that I found (containing 3 actual shapes & 2 comments) had an ID of 15361! Not the 1-5 I was expecting.

Code accordingly.

Comment: Excellent exercise! Observe how your answer is much longer than your question. That is because the question is of much lower quality, in fact inadequate. Only your answer specifies that you want to find a shape by its location on a worksheet. Of course, the system is designed to identify shapes by name. Since every shape has a name finding one never was a problem. BTW, the ID identifies the shape's shape. But within the` Shapes` *Collection* each item has an `Index`.

Comment: I am exploring a related 'quirk' where Excel will tell you there are n shapes from Shapes.Count but will give you an error on the last one.  I can only find n-1 thus far. (No, the index does not start at 0.)

Comment: Related to this: Mysterious shapes that cause looping through shapes to crash: Ghost Shapes!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387454/why-does-my-code-crash-when-i-loop-through-shapes-in-excel-ghost-shapes/64387455#64387455