# Why does my code crash when I loop through shapes in Excel? Ghost Shapes?

Tags: excel, vba

Writing a program to locate & manipulate shapes in Excel using VBA, I ran across an error I could NOT figure out! (What else is new?)  After half a day of picking through Watches, I have come to the conclusion that sometimes Excel keeps leftover shapes by accident. Or, at least for a reason I cannot fathom.

```
. . .
    i=1
    For Each shp In .Shapes
            arrShapes(i, 1) = shp.TopLeftCell.Address
        arrShapes(i, 2) = shp.TopLeftCell.row
        arrShapes(i, 3) = shp.TopLeftCell.Column
        arrShapes(i, 4) = shp.ID
        
    Next shp
```

This code runs fine MOST of the time, but occasionally I’d get the error “Run-time Error 1004:  Application-defined or object-defined error”
While the .Shapes.Count gave me 7 shapes, the last one caused the error. I could only find 6 shapes on my sheet. (4 inserted ones + 2 Comments).

(Yes, I considered an index that started at 0, but that wasn't it and it created a new out-of-range error. Besides, Count was 7 and there is no .Shapes.Item 0  in the watcher.)

(Reference to [How to find a Shape in MS Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380490/how-to-find-a-shape-in-ms-excel/64380491?noredirect=1#comment113844632_64380491))

My solution is below. Happy to hear others' takes on it.

Comment: "the last one caused the error" since you don't mention what the error was, it's not clear what the real "problem" is here.  If it's just that you found an "extra" shape on your worksheet you weren't expect, that doesn't seem to warrant documenting it here.  If it's more than that, then it seems like adding some actual *specific* details would be useful.

Comment: The error was 424 - it's clarified in my "specific" answer below. Just trying to share knowledge, Tim.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this further, Excel seems to think there is a mysterious 7th shape on the sheet. (Item7 under .Shapes). But this object has only about half the properties of any other shape.

In honor of Halloween, I dub it the “Ghost Shape”.

No idea where it came from. I can’t find it. I can’t see it on the screen. I don’t remember creating it – which is not to say I didn’t. But if I did create it, I’m 99.9% certain that I also deleted it!

Excel gave my Ghost Shape a name of “Line 28”.  It has a Top & Left location. (Nothing there) A Line.ForeColor and Visible is True.

BUT the Height and Width properties are both 0!

This at least gives me a way to identify them to filter them out.
So, I simply modified the code to:

```
. . . 
On Error Resume Next
. . .
i=1
For Each shp In .Shapes
    If shp.Height = 0 And shp.Width = 0 _
            Or Err.Number = 424 Then
        shp.Delete        
    Else
        arrShapes(i, 1) = shp.TopLeftCell.Address
        arrShapes(i, 2) = shp.TopLeftCell.row
        arrShapes(i, 3) = shp.TopLeftCell.Column
        arrShapes(i, 4) = shp.ID
    End If
Next shp
```

This eliminated the error from the Ghost Shape, and deleted them as they were found.

Does that make me a GhostBuster?

Comment: I tried IsEmpty, Is Nothing, IsObject, IsNull, IsMissing, IsError on shp and various attributes, but always got a 424 error.  I should add that this is difficult to test because it's hard to intentionally create 'Ghost Shapes' for testing. So, I'd appreciate any contributions. Thx.